# Given multiple lists of numbers find the sum that is the closest to a specific number

Tags: algorithm, search, combinations

I'm trying to solve a problem and i'm not really sure how to do it.
Basically, the input is composed of a set of lists with numbers and a number which look like this:

```
Input Data
    A = [0,3,6]
    B = [0.5,0.63,1]
    C = [0.12,0.3,0.7]
    D = [0.12,0.3,0.7]
    E = [0.5,0.25,0.1]
    F = [0.5,0.25,0.1]

    Number = 8.3
```

I need to find all possible combinations that sumed up gives a value that is 8.3 or close to 8.3 but also there are a few conditions:

Values from C list needs to be smaller or equal than values from D list

Also values from E list needs to be smaller or equal than values from F list
From each list i can choose only one number at a time

```
For example: 0 + 0.5 + 0.3 + 0.12 + 0.5 + 0.5 -> is wrong because 0.3 is bigger than 0.12


    But, 0 + 0.5 + 0.3 + 0.7 + 0.5 + 0.5 -> is correct because the value from C list(0.3) is bigger than 0.7 and value from E list(0.5) is equal to F list(0.5)
```

Comment: Since C and D are the same list, you can just choose any 2 items from C. Then proceed as if the smaller value came from C and the larger came from D. This is also true for E and F.

Comment: Why not choose 6 + 1 + 0.12 + 0.12 + 0.5 + 0.5 to get 8.24? is that the best solution?